# Where to get intel's Tbb for gcc on windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, intel

Where to get intel's Tbb for gcc on windows? I've checked here:  http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=182 but it only consists of versions for vs.

Comment: Three second search: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-threading-building-blocks-purchase/?wapkw=tbb

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry Hans but I meant 'free' version of tbb not commercial.

Comment: Intel giving something away for free?  Hehe, the processor manuals are free.  The rest requires a law suit, a gun or a division.

Comment: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=182

Comment: @smallB: Hans is one of those old cranky bags that hang around here all day instead of getting some sunlight and fresh air.

Comment: @hanns - intel giving away a library which enables you to use their processors for a task that you might otherwise use a competitors FPGA/GPU/DSP for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBB is under GPL2

You can get the sources (and builds for various platforms) from 
http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/file.php?fid=77